# My navbar is overlapping with my logo when I decrease the size of my browser

Tags: html, css

Basically, when I try to decrease the size of my browser, it starts to overlap with my logo element on the left side, resulting in the navigation options becoming hidden.

This is the HTML for my header+nav:

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="bitbird.png" class="logo"></a>
            <ul class="navlist">
                <li class="navitem"><a href="about.html" class="navlink" id="navlink1">Om Bitbird</a></li>

                <li class="navitem"><a href="artists.html" class="navlink" id="navlink2">Artister</a></li>

                <li class="navitem"><a href="contact.html" class="navlink" id="navlink3">Kontakt</a></li>

                <li class="navitem"><a href="topsongs.html" class="navlink" id="navlink4">Topplåtar</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </header>
```

This is the CSS for my navbar

```
.navlist {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.navitem {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: auto;

}

.navlink {
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem;

}
```

Btw, header's display is set to flex.

Comment: I'd probably make the `<nav>` display:flex instead of using float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a semantic problem in HTML. your logo shouldn't be inside the tag nav.thats the reason why it overlaps. should be like this :

```
<header> 
 <a href="#">
   <img src="#">
 </a>
 <nav>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Also, I recommend you use BEM to organize better your classes and in CSS style use * to make global styles.
Finally, use Flexbox or CSS Grid for everything instead of using float. It's better for responsiveness.

Here is the code with better solution:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration:none;
}

html{
  font-size:100%;
}

body{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.header{
  background-color:red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.header__nav{
  background-color:yellow;
}

.header__nav-list{
  display:flex;
}

.header__nav-item{
  margin: 0 .5rem 0 2rem;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="#"><img src="#" class="header__logo"></a>
        <nav class="header__nav">
          <ul class="header__nav-list">
                <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="about.html" class="header__nav-link" id="navlink1">Om Bitbird</a></li>

                <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="artists.html" class="header__nav-link" id="navlink2">Artister</a></li>

                <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="contact.html" class="header__nav-link" id="navlink3">Kontakt</a></li>

                <li class="header__nav-item"><a href="topsongs.html" class="header__nav-link" id="navlink4">Topplåtar</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    </header>

Here it is the snippet of the code.
```

I had some background colors for you to visualize better. you can erase later. Feel free to use this code for you. Hope I did help you. Any questions you have asked, I will gladly help you.

Comment: Thank you! This helped alot, very understandable answer even for a newbie like me.

Comment: Oh, I am really glad that you did understand my explanation and was helpful for you. Ask anytime you need  :)  If you liked my answer please click of the arrow up  also :) thank  you

Comment: Already upvoted! I'll probably be back with a couple questions soon!